# Drools condition cannot retrieve object from Map with Enum key

Tags: parameters, enums, hashmap, drools

I'm migrating an application that used drools 5.3 on the newer drools 6.5 version. Here is an extract of my fact :

```
public class Convention {
  [...]
  private Map<ECommissionType, List<Commission>> commissions = new HashMap<>();
  [...]
}
```

and a very simple enumeration :

```
public enum ECommissionType {
  ACQ,RIS,POF,[...]
}
```

I'm using a decision table, and one of the condition header is the following (assuming `$convention` is properly initialized in a former condition and is an instance of the `Convention` class shown) :

```
$comm : Commission() from $convention.getCommissions().get(ECommissionType.$1)
```

In the lines defining my rules, I'm using one of the values of the enumeration, for instance `POF` or `RIS`. Drools 5.3 is compiling this condition, but drools 6.5 is not. It fails with this error message :

```
Unable to Analyse Expression $convention.getCommissions().get(ECommissionType.RIS)):
sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class : [Rule name='B_CommissionLigne_98']
```

Any insights to go through this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
$conv : Commission from $convention.getCommissions().get(ECommissionType.$1)
```

You need to add a `()` *after* `Commission`.

It's possible that something in the considerable change in the parser and expression evaluation mechanics between 5.3 and 6.0 has introduced a bug.

**Edit** Yes, a bug. Shortening some names but using the same types, this avoids the problem:

```
rule comms
when
  $conv: Convention()
  $comm: Comm() from (ArrayList)($conv.getComms()).get(Type.AAA)
then
```

(Why don't you use an EnumMap??)

Comment: True, I forgot two parenthesis. I added them to my post. But I do not understand really your answer. I'm using this syntax in a lot of Decision Tables with a `List` on the right of a `from` keyword with a single object on the left. It's working on both drools 5 and drools 6 to apply an action on the objects of the list. I simply want to call a method (a setter) on all the objects of the list in an action column of the decision table.

Comment: BTW, I'll have a look at EnumMap, never heard of it.

Comment: Oops, now I was confused, I don't know by what, maybe it was just the missing parentheses ;-) See my revised answer, and I'll investigate.

Comment: @Wis If you care enough you might raise a JIRA on the Drools error reporting site or write a mail to the Drools user list.

Comment: that may be dark magic, but it is indeed working. I'll try to send this topic as a bug reference to drools dev team. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1397 created (with code extracts displayed very badly...)

Comment: Reproduced and fixed (see linked jira). I also suggested 2 simpler workarounds there.

Comment: @MarioFusco Thanks for the umpteenth time ;-)

Comment: @Wis No black magic, I've just been following Drools for a long time and (occasionally) have a hunch about the stone where the bug hides ;-)